# Python, where i am wrong for the function to remove vowels in a string?

Tags: python

I am following the codecademy tutorial, the question is "Define a function called anti_vowel that takes one string, text, as input and returns the text with all of the vowels removed.

For example: anti_vowel("Hey You!") should return "Hy Y!"."

The code:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    textlist = list(text)
    print textlist
    for k in textlist:
        if k in"aeiouAEIOU":
            print k
            textlist.remove(k)
    return "".join(textlist)
```

The error is "Oops, try again. Your function fails on anti_vowel("Hey look Words!"). It returns "Hy lk Words!" when it should return "Hy lk Wrds!"."
I don't know why still an extra 'o' there? Could anyone tell me what cause the error? Thank you!

Comment: Because: 1. `remove` only removes the *first* appearance of its argument; and 2. you're changing the length of the list while iterating over it (this is A Bad Idea).

Comment: Thanks @jornsharpe , your point two is very important. But if the .remove() only removes the first appearance, why in the example of the error: "look" returns "lk"

Comment: Because (only) two of the letters you *do* iterate over are `'o'`s

Comment: Note that the trivial fix is to iterate over a *copy* of the list: `for k in textlist[:]:`, or just the original string: `for k in text:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is already explained in the comments by @jonrsharpe.

I would like to show you an optimised version, which does work and uses list comprehension:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    return "".join([x for x in text if x not in "aeiouAEIOU"])

print anti_vowel("Hey look Words!")
```

output:

```
Hy lk Wrds!
```

Answer (score 3):

Python happens to use index when iterating over lists. Modifying the list is as mentioned a bad idea because the documentation says not to do so and doesn't specify the behavior. This is what happens

```
Hey look Words!
^
Hey look Words!
 ^ found 'e' so we remove it
Hy look Words!
  ^ note that we stepped one step but the removal made us skip 'y'
...
Hy look Words!
    ^ found 'o' so we remove it
Hy lok Words
     ^ again we stepped one step, but the removal made us skip 'o'
...
Hy lok Words!
        ^ found 'o' so we remove the first o
Hy lk Words!
         ^ again we stepped one step, but removing a letter before the cursor make us skip 'r'.
...
Hy lk Words!
           ^ consider youself lucky python happens to check the actual length of the list at each iteration - or the cursor would continue into the wilderness.
```

The lesson learned is that not modify a container while you iterate unless the documentation clearly says you can do so (sometimes it's allowed under specific restrictions).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't modify a list while you are iterating over it because you change the length and it doesn't iterate as you expect instead you can use `yield` to return a generator of none vowels then join it :

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    for k in textlist:
        if k not in"aeiouAEIOU":
              yield k
```

Demo:

```
print ''.join(anti_vowel("Hey look Words!"))
Hy lk Wrds!
```

Note that in this case you don't need to convert your string to list.

Also as a more elegant way you can do it with `re.sub` :

```
import re
def anti_vowel(text):
  return re.sub(r'[aeiou]+','',text,flags=re.I)
```